# Angular Material Chip Input with comma as separator wont allow '<' (less than)

Tags: angular, angular-material

In the [material](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lyqkbervyjy?file=app%2Fchips-input-example.ts) example of Chips with input they use Enter and Comma as keys to trigger an Add event. However, it doesnt seem to be able to tell the difference between COMMA and SHIFT+COMMA. This results in me not being able to enter a '<' less than symbol in the field. Is there a way I can specify only nonshifted commas should Add the chip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directive listens to keydown key codes. Since the shift is a separate key, there can be no distinction between shift-comma ('<') and just comma. About the only thing you can do is turn off comma response - in the demo it is deliberately added by the `[matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"` option - default behaviour is enter key only.

Comment: I still want comma to be trigger the add though

Comment: You would have to implement your own comma handler via events from the input field, and turn off the automatic handler for comma. I'm not sure that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your input
[matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"

use this site to find key codes: keycode.info

Comment: The problem is that "," has a keycode of 188 "COMMA" and "<" has the same keycode of 188 "COMMA". There is no keycode specifically for comma or the less than sign.

Answer (score 0):

As you already found out, the problem is that both the comma and the `<` symbol share the same `keyCode`, `188`, and that's why they should have used `e.key` instead.

It looks like this issue has been fixed already, as if you go [`@angular/components/src/material/chips/chip-input.ts` and search for the `_emitChipEnd` function](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/chips/chip-input.ts#L142):

```
/** Checks to see if the (chipEnd) event needs to be emitted. */
_emitChipEnd(event?: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (!this._inputElement.value && !!event) {
    this._chipList._keydown(event);
  }
  if (!event || this._isSeparatorKey(event)) {
    this.chipEnd.emit({ input: this._inputElement, value: this._inputElement.value });

    if (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

You will see it only emits a `chipEnd` event if `_isSeparatorKey` returns `true`. Checking the implementation below, you'll see that for that to happen `hasModifierKey(event)` must return `false`:

```
/** Checks whether a keycode is one of the configured separators. */
private _isSeparatorKey(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  return !hasModifierKey(event) && new Set(this.separatorKeyCodes).has(event.keyCode);
}
```

If you go find that in the `@angular/cdk/keycodes` repo, you can see it was [added on the `7 Nov 2018`](https://github.com/angular/components/pull/13933/files/3e4ea4ec87da0fcfd52ffebac4bbf81ff7c5f42b):

```
/**
 * Checks whether a modifier key is pressed.
 * @param event Event to be checked.
 */
export function hasModifierKey(event: KeyboardEvent, ...modifiers: ModifierKey[]): boolean {
  if (modifiers.length) {
    return modifiers.some(modifier => event[modifier]);
  } 

  return event.altKey || event.shiftKey || event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey;
}
```

As you asked this question on the `13 Jun 18`, you were probably using a version of the library that didn't have that check in place, so you could fix the issue just by updating to the latest version.

However, the current implementation is still incorrect, as what if you want to use a separator character that is entered by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>some key</kbd>? It won't work.

The right solution would be to use `e.key` instead of checking modifier keys and using `e.keyCode`, especially considering `e.which` and `e.keyCode` are deprecated.

Anyway, if you need to check KeyboardEvent's properties values such as `e.key`, `e.code`, `e.which` or `e.keyCode`, you can use https://keyjs.dev:

[image: Key.js \ JavaScript KeyboardEvent's key codes & key identifiers]

**Disclaimer: I'm the author.**

Comment: @elie_ I see you asked about specifying separators as characters rather than key codes in your deleted "answers". As I point out above, that functionality should have been implemented differently to avoid these kinds of bugs and probably make it easier and more intuitive to use the component. Anyway, it is what it is, so if you want that functionality you would need to either open an issue on the `@angular/material` repo and wait or submit a PR yourself with the fix.